# Undefined subroutine CGI::radio

Tags: perl, cgi

I have an application about a student data,and i am trying to make a radio-group which has options about gender of the student. But it shows me the following error: Undefined subroutine CGI::radio
 at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/modify.pl line 196

```
   $cInput .= $q->div({-class => 'control-group'},
                    $q->label({-class => 'control-label', -for => 'gender'}, "Gender:"), 
                    $q->div({class => 'controls'}, 
                    $q->span({class => 'span12'},
                    $q->label({-class => 'blue'},
                    $q->radio-group({-id => 'gender', -name => 'gender', -values => ['M','F'],-labels => \%labels, -default => $cGender, 'true'})))));
```

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to call `$q->radio-group` but:

1. The `-` is being treated as a subtraction operator
2. The method is called `radio_group` (with an underscore)

See [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#CREATING-A-RADIO-BUTTON-GROUP)

Comment: Now it doesn't shows me the buttons just the values. What may be the problem?