# How to update an image file

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to update an image of a database that contains data about students. I have used filefield and i want that firstly to display the name of the image that already exists in databse and than to change it if i want.

```
$cInput_form .= $q->div({-class => 'control-group'},
                    $q->div({-class => 'controls'}, 
                    $q->div({-class => 'span12'},
                    $q->filefield({-name => 'myfile', -value => $image, -label => $image }))));
```

where $image is the name of the picture that i get from database. But the problem is that this name doesn't appears. It is 'No file choosen'. label doesn't work,  what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

IFAIK, file field cannot be pre-filled for security reason.

Comment: @AnaVani: You can't :-(

Comment: Is there any other way how to update an image that already exists in database?

Comment: @AnaVani: Sorry, as I said, it is not allowed for security reason.

Comment: OK thanks. Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296944/undefined-subroutine-cgiradio   i don't understand where is the problem